# Overflow-y set to hidden also disables horizontal scrolling

Tags: css

I want to disable vertical scrolling, For this slideshow project I'm making. But when I set overflow-y to **hidden** all (x, y) scrolling stops. How do I fix it? I have tried adding `overflow-x: scroll`. If I don't limit vertical scrolling and switch to the responsive device view on chrome or firefox (Ctrl+Shift+M), there's a large empty space at the bottom, which is the reason I want to disable vertical scrolling in the first place.

My code: https://codepen.io/dan6200/project/editor/ABRqpk

Comment: your project is read only, can you fix that ?

Comment: I don't think I can, I've got the free version.